# mysql REPLACE query with multiple primary keys

Tags: mysql, replace

so MYSQL's REPLACE command (not to be confused with the string replace function) replaces a row if there exist a column with the same primary key with the inserted data...

but what if I have two primary keys and I want to use both to specify the row to replace not just one of them....how do I specify mysql to use both keys rather than just one

Comment: A table, by definition, can only have a single PK.  Do you mean unique keys?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant a multi-column primary key.

Comment: You cannot have two primary keys. Do you mean you have a compound primary key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't make a difference, it's the same syntax.  Just be sure you have both keys specified as columns.  For example:

```
REPLACE INTO `my_table` ( `key1`, `key2`, `othercolumn1` /* , ... */ )
  VALUES ( 'widgets', 14, 'Blue widget with purple trim' );
```

**EDIT**

Here's my test I ran in my test database to make sure I wasn't about to destroy your data.  Of course, I encourage you to try it out if you're unsure!

```
CREATE SCHEMA `my_testdb`;
USE `my_testdb`;
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `key1` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `key2` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `othercolumn1` VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (`key1`, `key2`) );
REPLACE INTO `my_table` ( `key1`, `key2`, `othercolumn1` )
  VALUES ( 'widgets', 14, 'Green widget with fuchsia trim' );
REPLACE INTO `my_table` ( `key1`, `key2`, `othercolumn1` )
  VALUES ( 'widgets', 15, 'Yellow widget with orange trim' );
REPLACE INTO `my_table` ( `key1`, `key2`, `othercolumn1` )
  VALUES ( 'thingamabobs', 14, 'Red widget with brown trim' );
REPLACE INTO `my_table` ( `key1`, `key2`, `othercolumn1` )
  VALUES ( 'widgets', 14, 'Blue widget with purple trim' );
SELECT * FROM `my_table`;
```

This is my result:

```
key1          key2  othercolumn1
widgets       14    Blue widget with purple trim
widgets       15    Yellow widget with orange trim
thingamabobs  14    Red widget with brown trim
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I think I see what you're talking about in the documentation, the confusion over unique columns:

> It is possible for a single row to replace more than one old row if the table contains multiple unique indexes and the new row duplicates values for different old rows in different unique indexes.  —*MySQL Documentation*

That's referring to a rather contrived circumstance in which the row you're replacing with conflicts not just with an existing primary key, but with other unique columns as well.  Here's another example to illustrate this point:

```
CREATE SCHEMA `my_testdb2`;
USE `my_testdb2`;
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `key1` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `key2` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `color` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `othercolumn1` VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (`key1`, `key2`) );
REPLACE INTO `my_table` ( `key1`, `key2`, `color`, `othercolumn1` )
  VALUES ( 'widgets', 14, 'green', 'Green widget with fuchsia trim' );
REPLACE INTO `my_table` ( `key1`, `key2`, `color`, `othercolumn1` )
  VALUES ( 'widgets', 15, 'yellow', 'Yellow widget with orange trim' );
REPLACE INTO `my_table` ( `key1`, `key2`, `color`, `othercolumn1` )
  VALUES ( 'thingamabobs', 14, 'red', 'Red widget with brown trim' );
REPLACE INTO `my_table` ( `key1`, `key2`, `color`, `othercolumn1` )
  VALUES ( 'widgets', 14, 'yellow', 'Yellow widget with purple trim' );
SELECT * FROM `my_table`;
```

Notice how the last REPLACE operation not only conflicts with the (`key1`, `key2`) primary key, of the first REPLACE, but also with the unique color of the second one.  In this case, BOTH rows are deleted before the last REPLACE operation is performed so that the result is no conflict.  You'll end up with just two rows:

```
key1          key2  color   othercolumn1
widgets       14    yellow  Yellow widget with purple trim
thingamabobs  14    red     Red widget with brown trim
```

Both the row with (`key1`, `key2`) equal to ('widgets', 14) **AND** the row with the color 'yellow' were blown away due to the new row conflicting with multiple unique constraints on the table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: is that true...the way I understand it is that REPLACE will replace if ANY of the multiple keys are duplicates....the way I want it is that if BOTH of the keys are duplicate, not just one of them...correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes, it's true.  I just ran it on a test database I created to make sure I'm not misremembering, and it only replaces the values where both columns match up, not either/or.  When in doubt, give it a whirl!

Comment: @user841626: That's how I read the documentation, too. You may just have to test it to see how it behaves, though.

Comment: I added an test example and a clarification what I think is confusing the situation.  Don't forget to upvote and mark my answer as accepted if this is the solution!  ;)  Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!