# MySql replace with multiple primary keys

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has three primary keys and references three other tables 
[image]

Here is the table scheema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS training_matrix_reference(
  employee INT NOT NULL,
  training_matrix INT NOT NULL,
  training_record INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (employee, training_matrix,training_record),
  FOREIGN KEY (employee) REFERENCES employees(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (training_matrix) REFERENCES training_matrix_courses(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (training_record) REFERENCES training_records(m_id)
)
```

I'm trying to craft a `REPLACE` statement which updates the `training_record` column or `training_matrix` column or both columns *or* creates a new row if not exists, but I also need to check that the employee belongs to the same company.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
REPLACE INTO `training_matrix_reference` 
  ( employee, training_matrix, training_record ) (
    SELECT id, '5', '100'
    FROM employees
    WHERE id =22
    AND company =64
    )
```

So my theory was that this should have replaced the first row in the table, updating `training_record` to `100` but in fact it actually created a new row:

```
                                         22      |           5 |           100
```

[image]

My guess is that this happened because `training_record` is a primary key?

But I'm not sure that removing the primary keys/references is the right way to go as this table is used as a many to many table in other queries.

Effectively  what I'm trying to do is:

```
REPLACE INTO `training_matrix_reference` 
  ( employee, training_matrix, training_record ) 
  VALUES
  (22,33,18) 
  WHERE 
  employee = 22
  and training_matrix = 5  
  and training_record = 2189
```

But obviously a replace statement doesn't have a where clause.

I did check out these similar questions:

[MySQL REPLACE INTO on multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450249/mysql-replace-into-on-multiple-keys)

[mysql REPLACE query with multiple primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671631/mysql-replace-query-with-multiple-primary-keys)

But unfortunately MySql is not my strong suit and I could really use some help.

I hope I explained things clearly, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PRIMARY KEY of the training_matrix_reference table is the *combination* of three columns. The table doesn't have *multiple* primary keys, it has a *single* PRIMARY KEY.

The REPLACE syntax you have is equivalent to performing:

```
DELETE FROM training_matrix_reference 
  WHERE employee        = 22
    AND training_matrix = 5
    AND training_record = 100
; 
INSERT INTO training_matrix_reference (employee, training_matrix, training_record)
VALUES (22, 5, 100);
;
```

The DELETE action only removes rows where the entire primary key is matched. Given the information you provided, we'd expect a row to be added to the table.

Did you have a question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess the question would be, is it possible to `set training_record= 100 where employee = 22 and training_matrix = 5` like you would in an `insert` using `replace`?

Comment: @andrew" No, that's not possible with REPLACE, given that `training_record` is part of the PRIMARY KEY constraint. If the PRIMARY KEY of the table were just the two columns `(employee,training_matrix)`, then you could use either `REPLACE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statements to change (22,5,2189) to (22,5,100). (But that would mean you could have only one row in the table for a given (employee, training_matrix), e.g. (22,5) would appear only once in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I think I'm beginning to wrap my head around it now +1

Answer (score 0):

you should make a joining table between (employee, training_matrix_reference)
or dispense at lest one relation

Comment: Can you please add some code to clarify what you mean?